# Lost AWS SQS messages

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send messages to AWS SQS using the SqsAsyncClient in the AWS SDK for Java.

I created 100,000 Dummy Data, cut them into 10 pieces and send them to sqsAsyncClient.sendMessageBatch, but when I look at the AWS Console, only 38730 or 37520 or 38490 messages are available.

In other words, more than 60000 messages are missing, so what's going on that's causing them to disappear?

The SQS I am trying to use is FIFO Queue and I have content based deduplication and high throughput FIFO Queue enabled as well.

Here is the code

```java
@Component
public class QueueMessagePublisher {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueMessagePublisher.class);

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.sqs.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    private SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public QueueMessagePublisher(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.sqsAsyncClient = SqsAsyncClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                        AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                                accessKey,
                                secretKey)))
                .build();
    }

    public void send() throws JsonProcessingException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> appPushes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
            appPushes.add(
                    SendMessageBatchRequestEntry.builder()
                            .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .messageGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .messageDeduplicationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .messageBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new AppPush(String.valueOf(i))))
                            .build()
            );
        }

        final List<List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry>> partition = Lists.partition(appPushes, 10);

        final String queueUrl = sqsAsyncClient.getQueueUrl(GetQueueUrlRequest
                .builder()
                .queueName("test.fifo")
                .build()
        ).get().queueUrl();


        for (List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> messages : partition) {
            SendMessageBatchRequest sendMessageBatchRequest = SendMessageBatchRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .entries(Collections.unmodifiableCollection(messages))
                    .build();

            sqsAsyncClient.sendMessageBatch(sendMessageBatchRequest)
                    .thenAccept(sendMessageBatchResponse -> {
                        log.info("Send Message Success : {} / Send Message Fail : {}", sendMessageBatchResponse.successful().size(), sendMessageBatchResponse.failed().size());
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have content based deduplication enabled, are you sure the messages aren't being removed because they are duplicates of other messages?

Comment: @MarkB 
Yes, there is no duplication of messages because we are using the index value in the forloop. Using the SqsClient, we see that we have 100M in SQS, which is fine.

Comment: So it's just the web console that is showing the wrong number?